# SwiftUI VideoPlayer fails to play when video has .aac audio

Tags: swift, swiftui

My app has a VideoPlayer which works great for most videos, but recently when attempting to play a video with .aac audio, the player will not work.

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
VideoPlayer(player: player)
   .onAppear() {
       player.play()
}
```

Even if I download the video, and export to camera roll, it will not play.  I suspect the audio channel is out of sync, or corrupt - but I'd like to be able to either strip the audio channel off to allow playback, or at least detect the corrupt channel and inform the user.

The XCode logs only show:

```
[AQ]      AudioQueueObject.cpp:401   AudioConverterNew from AudioQueueNew returned 1718449215
io:     4 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved
client:    4 ch,  48000 Hz, aac  (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1024 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
```

Comment: Can you offer that `a video with .aac audio` file?

Comment: I really can't, I'm sorry.  But I will say, when downloaded to my MacBook, it plays fine in QuickTime or VLC.